# Is the operation $i = x + y * \text{width}$ reversible?

Tags: transformation, programming

In game programming, there is this very common operation we do to index positions in a two-dimensional matrix over a one-dimensional array. We basically associate the value $a_{xy}$ of some matrix $A$ with width $w$ to the index $i = x + y * w$ of the array. This image illustrates the overall concept, but it can be used for a myriad of other things:
[image: x + y * w demonstration]

However, I was recently wondering whether this operation is reversible; that is, having an index in the array and the width of the matrix, is it possible to obtain the corresponding $(x,y)$?

From my experience with mathematics, I was under the impression that this operation is both injective (since, with a fixed width, every $(x,y)$ position has a single corresponding index), and surjective (since all indexes were generated from at least one position). Nevertheless, I was unable to come up with an inverse of this transformation that didn't result in x being dependent on the y or vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, there is an inverse. That doesn't mean that it's a pretty one.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be happy even if it isn't the prettiest, as long as the x and y can be found. It's kinda rare for me to need to work backwards like this, but I got really curious about whether it was possible or not :D

Comment: `y = i/w` (truncating integer division) and `x = i % w` (remainder operator) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically we have (assuming that $w > 0$ and $x, y \ge 0$ are integers)
$$
 i \bmod w = (x + y \cdot w) \bmod w = x \bmod w = x
$$
because $x$ is in the range $0, \ldots, w-1$, and
$$
 w \cdot y \le i \le w \cdot y + w - 1 < w \cdot (y+1)\\
\implies  y \le \frac iw < y+1 \implies y = \left\lfloor \frac iw \right\rfloor \, .
$$

In many programming languages this can be computed as

```
x = i % w  # remainder operator
y = i / w  # truncating integer division
```

Comment: I couldn't exactly understand your proof for $y$. How did you come to $w⋅y≤i<w⋅(y+1)$, and why does it imply the truncating division?

Comment: @Carmo: $i$ is at least $yw$, and at most $yw + w-1 < w(y+1)$. That implies $y \le \frac iw < y+1$, which means that $y$ is the largest integer $\le \frac iw$. That is what truncating integer division does: Compute the quotient and round down to the next integer.

Comment: Oh, I understand now! Thank you so much for the answer!

Also, could you please add the $y≤{i\over w}<y+1$ to your answer? I feel like it would make the truncation part easier to understand for the "mathematically-impaired" like me xD